# placing two images side by side, opencv 2.3, c++

Tags: opencv

I #m reading two images and want to get third one which is just combination of two. 
img_object and img_scene don't have same size.

```
    int main( int argc, char** argv )
        Mat combine;

        Mat img_object = imread( object_filename, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
        Mat img_scene = imread(  scene_filename , CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
    if( !img_object.data || !img_scene.data )
      { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }


       namedWindow( "Display window oject", 0 );// Create a window for display.


       namedWindow( "Display window scene ", 0 );


       namedWindow( "Display window combine ", 0 );

       imshow( "Display window oject", img_object );
       imshow( "Display window scene", img_scene );   
       imshow( "Display window scene", combine );   
 waitKey(0);
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

There is a very simple way of displaying two images side by side. The following function can be used which is provided by opencv.

```
Mat image1, image2;
hconcat(image1,image2,image1);//Syntax-> hconcat(source1,source2,destination);
```

This function can also be used to copy a set of columns from an image to another image.

```
Mat image;
Mat columns=image.colRange(20,30);
hconcat(image,columns,image);
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up very easy

Comment: I tried hconcat with different number of rows it crashes. Works only if number of rows are same. but works fine if number of cols are different

Comment: That's the idea. For variable number of rows, use vconcat function. But again in this function, number of columns has to be same. Using these functions eliminates the use of confusing "for" loops.

Comment: It must be the same number of rows and the same type of data, but otherwise works great.

Answer (score 3):

If the images are not the same size, `combine`'s width will be equal to the sum of the widths, but the height must be the bigger of the heights of the two images.

Define the combination image like this:

```
Mat combine(max(img_object.size().height, img_scene.size().height), img_object.size().width + img_scene.size().width, CV_8UC3);
```

Note that we're just creating a new `Mat` object with height equal to the maximum height and width equal to the combined width of the pictures (if you need a small margin between the pictures, you need to account for that here).

Then, you can define regions of interest for each side inside `combine` (using a convenient `Mat`constructor), and finally copy each image to the corresponding side (here I assume the object goes on the left and the scene goes on the right):

```
Mat left_roi(combine, Rect(0, 0, img_object.size().width, img_object.size().height));
img_object.copyTo(left_roi);
Mat right_roi(combine, Rect(img_object.size().width, 0, img_scene.size().width, img_scene.size().height));
img_scene.copyTo(right_roi);
```

*Edit:* Fixed the typo that TimZaman pointed out.

Comment: Following ur code, I'm getting 0 error. Displaying combine image or saving, getting just a black window. I'm getting no image.

Comment: img_object_size().width should be img_object.size().width .. i cant edit your post because stackoverflow wants at least 6 characters to be changed, *deep sigh*

Answer (score 3):

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Function to draw several images to one image.
// Small images draws into cells of size cellSize.
// If image larger than size of cell ot will be trimmed.
// If image smaller than cellSize there will be gap between cells.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
char showImages(string title, vector<Mat>& imgs, Size cellSize) 
{
char k=0;
    namedWindow(title);
    float nImgs=imgs.size();
    int   imgsInRow=ceil(sqrt(nImgs));     // You can set this explicitly
    int   imgsInCol=ceil(nImgs/imgsInRow); // You can set this explicitly

    int resultImgW=cellSize.width*imgsInRow;
    int resultImgH=cellSize.height*imgsInCol;

    Mat resultImg=Mat::zeros(resultImgH,resultImgW,CV_8UC3);
    int ind=0;
    Mat tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<imgsInCol;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<imgsInRow;j++)
        {
            if(ind<imgs.size())
            {
            int cell_row=i*cellSize.height;
            int cell_col=j*cellSize.width;
            imgs[ind].copyTo(resultImg(Range(cell_row,cell_row+tmp.rows),Range(cell_col,cell_col+tmp.cols)));
            }
            ind++;
        }
    }
    imshow(title,resultImg);
    k=waitKey(10);
    return k;
}
```

Comment: I have 12 frames in my vector<Mat> imgs. Individual frame size is 176x144. My program is crashing at   imgs[ind].copyTo(resultImg(Range(cell_row,cell_row+tmp.rows),Range(cell_col,cell_col+tmp.cols))); for first iteration. Any idea why?

Comment: May be you didn't set cellSize?

Comment: Thanks. I am setting cellsize equal to my individual image size. Its 176x144.

Comment: It also assumes that images in vector have CV_8UC3 element type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a loop, supposing that your images have the same size :

```
Mat combine = Mat::zeros(img_object.rows,img_object.cols *2,img_object.type());
for (int i=0;i<combine.cols;i++) {
    if (i < img_object.cols) {
         combine.col(i) = img_object.col(i);
    } else {
         combine.col(i) = img_scene.col(i-img_object.col);
    }
}
```

I didn't tested it, but that's the way you can do this

Comment: img_object and img_scene don't have same size.

Comment: Hi, this method doesn't work, you can't do A.row(j) = A.row(i);  please try A.row(j).copyTo(A.row(i));

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put multiple images side by side, just try this.

```
Mat combine = Mat::zeros(img_buff[0].rows, 
img_buff[0].cols * (int)img_index.size(), img_buff[0].type());

int cols = img_buff[0].cols;
for (int i=0;i<combine.cols;i++) {
    int fram_index = i / img_buff[0].cols;
    cout<<fram_index<<endl;   
    img_buff[fram_index].col(i % cols).copyTo(combine.col(i));
}
imshow("matching plot", combine);
```

Please pay attention, when you copy columns form one image to another do this:

```
A.row(j).copyTo(A.row(i));
```

Don't do this:

```
A.row(j) = A.row(i);
```