# How can I add features from different images and merge them into a final image

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have some input images which have the same dimensions, each of which may contain one or more blobs. I know how to load the image and convert it to binary but I want to be able to add all found blobs from any amount of images and paste them into a final image (which will start out blank) and be the same size as one of the input images. This is not an attempt to stitch images or concatenate them horizontally.

I don't know if opencv or pillow is better for this as I have very little experience or knowledge in feature extraction.

**Code**

```
import cv2

# use cv2 imread method to load image
img1 = cv2.imread("im1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("im2.jpg")

# make bw image
im1_gray = cv2.imread("im1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im2_gray = cv2.imread("im2.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# get threshold and binary image
(thresh, im_bw1) = cv2.threshold(im1_gray, 128, 255,
                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# save binary image 1
im_out1 = "bw_image_1"
ext = ".png"
im_name = im_out1 + "_" + str(thresh) + ext
cv2.imwrite(im_name, im_bw1)

# get threshold and binary image
(thresh, im_bw2) = cv2.threshold(im1_gray, 128, 255,
                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# save binary image 2
im_out2 = "bw_image_2"
ext = ".png"
im_name = im_out2 + "_" + str(thresh) + ext
cv2.imwrite(im_name, im_bw2)
```

**Input images**

[image: im1.jpg]
[image: im2.jpg]

**Desired output**

I don't know how to do this manually, but the output for this would be either a white or grey background with two black blobs in it.

[image: desired_output.jpg]

If either of the input images had two blobs in it and the other image had three blobs the output image would have five blobs, with positions equal to that of their position in the original image(s), it does not matter if they overlap.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to give some more examples of input image and the outputs you want. I guess you want to crop out the black circles and paste them in another blank image.

Comment: Yes I want to crop out the blobs and paste all of them (for the whole image set) into a single image.

Comment: I don't know how to do this manually, but the output for this would be either a white or grey background with two black blobs in it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before on opencv c++, there should be the same function on python3, hconcat, [placing two images side by side, opencv 2.3, c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044404/placing-two-images-side-by-side-opencv-2-3-c)

Comment: Hi, I have clarified the desired output as I think the original wording wasn't specific enough.

Comment: The first 2 images are the inputs?

Comment: Yes, first tow images are the inputs, there could be 30 or more input images of a similar image, i.e. a greyish background with one or more blobs in the image.

Comment: Does all of them have the same dimentions?

Comment: Yes, all input images will have the same dimensions, output image will be of the same dimensions as any of the input images.